# JScrollBar custom scrollbar ui graphics leaves trail

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, jscrollbar

I am making a custom JScrollBar.

**ScrollBar.java**

```
public class ScrollBar extends JScrollBar {
    ScrollBar() {
        super();
        setUI(new CustomScrollBarUI());
    }
}
```

**CustomScrollBarUI.java**

```
public class CustomScrollBarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {
    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fill(trackBounds);
        g2d.draw(trackBounds);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(thumbBounds);
        g2d.draw(thumbBounds);
    }
}
```

However this leaves a white trail when scrolling down but clears when scrolling up.

I have tried quite a few things.

1. Add `super.method()`

[This square I'm animating is leaving a trail behind it, can anyone work out why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696457/this-square-im-animating-is-leaving-a-trail-behind-it-can-anyone-work-out-why)

[Repaint leaves trail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513345/repaint-leaves-trail)

[oval leaves the trail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253209/oval-leaves-the-trail)

So I added `super.paintThumb(g, c, thumbBounds)` and `super.paintTrack(g, c, trackBounds)` to both but nothing changed.

2. Clear the previous rectangle

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1265963

Added a bunch of variables to store the previous position

```
double last_posx = -1d;
double last_posy = -1d;
double last_posw = -1d;
double last_posh = -1d;
```

and clear the previous rectangle

```
if (last_posx != -1d) {
    g.clearRect((int) last_posx, (int) last_posy, (int) last_posw, (int) last_posh);
}
```

This causes the effect to increase more, so there is more white that is left behind.

3. Repaint the track

This one I thought of myself. So I added `super.paintTrack(g, c, super.getTrackBounds())` to repaint the track before the thumb is painted to try and clear the previous thumbs.

This resulted in the same effect as 1.

So what do I do to remove the white trail left behind?

**EDIT**

As mentioned by LuxxMiner, this solved it but I would like to know why.

**CustomScrollBarUI.java**

```
public class CustomScrollBarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {
    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fill(trackBounds);
        g2d.draw(trackBounds);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(thumbBounds);
//      g2d.draw(thumbBounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but removing `g2d.draw(thumbBounds);` fixed it for me...

Comment: Yes, this fixes the trail for me too. Perhaps it draws the thumbBounds itself?